# com.apple.developer.contacts.notes - xCode still shows an error after getting access to the entitlement

Tags: ios, xcode, entitlements

We asked Apple to allow us to access the contact note field (com.apple.developer.contacts.notes) which was accepted (for development, we do not need to publish the test app).

1. We created a provisioning profile which includes `com.apple.developer.contacts.notes`
2. Added an entitlement file to the project which sets the Boolean for using that entitlement to true.
3. We selected manual signing and choose the provisioning profile which includes com.apple.developer.contacts.notes
4. It still says that com.apple.developer.contacts.notes-Entitlement is missing although it is shown correctly in xCode in the entitlement list.

Is this a bug in xCode?

[image: Entitlement List]

xCode Version: 11.3.1

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried to remove/download a certificate in Keychain ?

Comment: Yes, I also tried it with a new certificate.

Comment: Hey! Do you have any news/updates? Thanks

Comment: @AlexanderKhitev I don't remember exactly, but I think we needed to contact the apple support to allow this entitlement. They need to allow that because some users store very sensitive information there.